# onclick ="return confirm(' ' )"not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the coding in my HTML page:

```html
    <input onclick="return  confirm('Delete Record?')"
        type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete">
```

Delete function is working but without pop out "Delete Record? " in Google Chrome ver38.

Delete function is working and with pop out "Delete Record?" in Internet Explorer.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: do you have any console error in chrome? try looking at it :)

Comment: By pop out you mean alert/confirm box, I guess! Chrome has changed it's alert/confirm box appearance compared to other browsers. Probably this is what you are pointing at. If you can add screen shots of both Chrome and IE it would be helpful.

Comment: Something to do with pop-up settings? See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=en amd  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529036/google-chrome-not-displaying-alert-popups-for-one-site

Comment: Thank you guys fro helping me but it still not works.It is weird because i have couple html page with this coding. Some of them can function(alert box popout) but some can't. I'm wondering the reason and solve this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try without 'return', like this:

```
<input onclick="confirm('Delete Record?')" type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete">
```

The return keyword doesn't always behave uniformly across browsers.